# Show failed or bad SSH login attempts in CentOS 8

Tags: centos, ssh

Under CentOS 8 I'm trying to find SSH failed login attempts.
Lastb returns:

```
# lastb

btmp begins Thu Jul  9 10:53:49 2020
```

Aureport returns some records (one examples is):

```
# aureport -au -i --failed 

Authentication Report
============================================
# date time acct host term exe success event
============================================
1. 06/25/2020 13:46:36 root 10.10.0.2 ssh /usr/sbin/sshd no 66
```

When i try to login with bad credentials aureport or lastb do not show new record. Where can i found failed SSH logins ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As sshd service managed by systemd, you should look into journal. For example:

```
$ journalctl -u sshd
 Jul 19 05:24:07 xx-1 sshd[30983]: Received disconnect from 43.254.220.207 port 59846:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
 Jul 19 05:24:07 xx-fsn1-1 sshd[30983]: Disconnected from invalid user ik 43.254.220.207 port 59846 [preauth]
 Jul 19 05:26:25 xx-1 sshd[30986]: Invalid user test from 139.213.220.70 port 62857
 Jul 19 05:26:25 xx-1 sshd[30986]: Received disconnect from 139.213.220.70 port 62857:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
 Jul 19 05:26:25 xx-1 sshd[30986]: Disconnected from invalid user test 139.213.220.70 port 62857 [preauth]
```

Comment: yes you are right, but i can see `-- Logs begin at Fri 2020-07-17 18:15:38 CEST, end at Mon 2020-07-20 09:37:22 CEST. --` and I'm trying to find older records ? Is it possible to find them ?

Comment: **journalctl --since="2020-01-01 00:00:00"** or **journalctl --since "2 hour ago"**

Comment: That's should make the job but i did not have enabled the persistent storage of log messages. So to make log storage persistent do https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159221/how-do-i-display-log-messages-from-previous-boots-under-centos-7)

Comment: @SimonLi The journal is rotated after some time or if disk space is used up. For more persistent logs, you can enable rsyslog (which should have already been enabled; it sounds like someone disabled it on your system) and everything will also be logged to the traditional files. There are many other ways to export the journal, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can always look at the logs at `/var/log/secure` to find the ssh logs. You can use grep to list out the exact details. Like if you are looking for a failed attempt you can use like
`grep -i "failed" /var/log/secure`

Comment: There is no such file

Comment: If the file is not present secure log is not enabled. Any way it will be available in message logs. Check like `grep -i "failed" /var/log/message`

Comment: Sorry, i do not have such file (message or secure)